# How to set Paypal Payment pro (direct payment) recurring payments?

Tags: paypal

I have a doubt regarding how to make recurring payments with Paypal Payment Pro(Direct Payment).Which API I should call first DoDirectPayment API OR CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API for making payment.Will calling CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile  API alone will make payment? I'm getting confused.

Binta

Comment: @PayPal_Robert answered your question, but make sure your account is indeed setup to work with DPRP and not the PayPal Manager / PayFlow API.  If your account is setup for PayFlow and you integrate everything using CreateRecuringPaymentsProfile you'll just end up getting a "DPRP is disabled for this merchant" error when you try to run it live.  I would recommend calling PayPal and asking them if you're on Website Payments Pro 3.0 or Payments Pro 2.0 (which is actually the newer version)

Answer (score 0):

For recurring payments based on credit card data ('DPRP'), you can immediately call `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` and the recurring payment will be created immediately.
`CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` will create the recurring payment and ensure it's billed on the period you told it to in the request.

Comment: So let me make clear once again.I don't need to call DoDirectPayment API.Is that right?

Comment: Thankyou for the information.I have one doubt too.Will the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile api response ACK=Success indicates that the recurring payment has been received by the paypal merchant account? Please help me one more time.Its very urgent.I'm asking this for recurring payments with direct payment pro scenario.

Comment: That's right - it will return ACK=Success. Note though, that ACK=Success merely means the API calls has been acknowledged. For `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`, I highly suggest also looking at the `PROFILEID` and `PROFILESTATUS` in the response.